# How to mimick polling of a Future in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I need to demonstrate asynchronous task handling and I am using a Callable object to do the async operation and I need to send a notification when the task is completed. So far I have:

```
Callable<String> task = () -> {
    writeToFile();
    return "Write to file op";
}
Future future = executor.submit(task);
Runnable poller = () -> {
    if(future!=null) {
        while(!future.isDone()) {
        }
        sendNotification("Completed " + future.get());
    }
}
poller.run();
```

I know that spinlocks are usually not thought of too highly, but I can't think of another simple way to mimick a traditional polling of an asynchronous operation. What can I use to replace the spinlock?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call `future.get()` directly? It's a blocking operation.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman, that will definitely work